# A bookmark option would be great

Tags: feature-request, questions

Often, a question that I can relate to, found its answers and I wish I could keep it somewhere for my future reference but, as is now, I can't store it in a library conveniently.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this exists already! You can click the star by the voting buttons to mark a question as a favorite, and then it'll show in [the favorites tab of your profile](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/54873/backyard-chef?tab=favorites). (Note that this is public; I doubt people look too often, but they can see what questions you've favorited.)